# JTAG basic question

Tags: jtag

I'm trying to understand how a JTAG connector looks. To successfully interface with a board, are there any alternatives to JTAG?

Will all the pins of the JTAG be clumped together, or can they be spread apart, like in different corners of the board?

I have a complex board I'm looking at, and it has a lot of TP (test points) on the board. Can any of them, together, form a JTAG?

Will there be any marking on the PCB to help identify JTAG?

Comment: A collection of test points migth form JTAG, but if they're not labelled the only way is to trace them back to the parts. What processor are you trying to access? Can you post a picture of the board?

Comment: The front of the board has a huge metal plate covering the whole board. Here's a blurred pic of the back of the board: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19240828/Boardie.png

Comment: That's .. quite blurred. I can't even see a part number on the large IC. The cluster of 10 pads on the bottom left looks like it might be the signal pins of ARM JTAG: http://www.jtagtest.com/pinouts/arm20 , although there's also a cluster of 9 pins on the bottom right which might be the back side of some sort of connector? Of course, it could be under the shield on the other side. Is that a SATA connector on the top?

Comment: Yes, the bottom 9 pins are from a connector, and the SATA connector is on top. How do I check if the 10 pins on the bottom left are sending signals? I only have a multimeter.

Comment: JTAG is an input, so even if it is JTAG you won't see anything. It might be outputting a constant voltage on Vref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JTAG is a port like any other (you also wouldn't want to have to connect five different cables to attach a LCD).
The layout itself doesn't matter although there are various standards (probably every vendor has its own standard, or two) but since it is possible to also use a high clock frequency (especially on TCK - 25MHz) you might want to route the lines together and not spread them apart with different lengths. 
If you want to access them via testpoints, why not place these together. Also note that it's usually possible to make a chain of multiple jtag devices. You will need to connect TDO to TDI of the next device and so on.
For the JTAG port you will usually have the following pins: TCK, TMS, TDI and TDO. Sometimes you might also want to have a Reset Pin where you can reset your peripherals but this is usually no JTAG requirement. You will have to check your devices if you need a reset.
Check the usual suspects for their typical connectors (ARM, Xilinx, Altera). These are pretty well specified and you can buy tools with the appropriate connectors (instead of having to make your own adapters).

Comment: Are there any alternatives for the JTAG?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do :)

Comment: I'm just educating myself on how to interface with a PCB ;)

Comment: I see :) In that case you should find out which IC is on the board and which interfaces it offers. But if you only have a multimeter you won't get far. Also, the device itself usually doesn't transmit anything by itself. It will be you who has to transmit to the device and then hope it responds :)

Comment: Aren't there debug messages coming out? Can it not be tracked with a multimeter? Like short jumps and falls in voltages? I'll accept your answer for now, 'cause I think my question has been answered sufficiently well by you and pjc50 to give me a good picture of what to do. Thanks!

Comment: Digital multimeters won't show you any change in signal shorter than hundreds of milliseconds. You need at the very least a JTAG probe and a scope for this. And a lot of patience. At the very least, confirm what the parts are on the board and that they support JTAG!

Comment: Seeing the board, do you have any recommendation as to what I could possibly use to probe or scope? All I could find was a cable which requires an explicit JTAG port. The board is ARM, but I'm trying to figure out a general method of working with an unknown board.

Comment: To me, this looks like the controller board of a SATA device, so your first chance would be to find any hints about the controller IC. Next idea would be to check for a JTAG port. I would look at the positions where there are a few pins close to each other, but without more information you just have too many pins to look at, especially if you do not expect to see a signal which originates from the device.
You could check some of the testpoints with a scope if you see "familiar" protocols, such as SPI or I2C but again, rather unlikely.